# Send MMS message to twilio from salesforce

Tags: integration, httppost, twilio

I am trying to send **MMS message** with **Twilio Api** from my Apex Code.
I have **working logic** which sends **SMS message** with Twilio API.

Based on this documentation [Sending Messages](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/send-messages?code-sample=code-send-an-sms-message&code-language=Python&code-sdk-version=7.x) we neeed to add the **"MediaUrl"** to our Request Body in order to send MMS.

> Sending an MMS message looks a lot like sending an SMS, but it includes a new parameter, MediaUrl. This parameter specifies the URL of the media you want to include with your message.

So my code looks like this :

```
String body = 'From=12222226666&To=17777777777&Body=SomeText&mediaUrl=https://demo.twilio.com/owl.png'; 
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint('callout:Twilio_Endpoint/2010-04-01/Accounts/aaaaaa/Messages.json');
req.setMethod('POST');
req.setbody(body);
Http http = new Http();
HTTPResponse response = http.send(req);
```

However after Code execution **I get only the SMS text on my phone** but NOT the image.
Also the message **is NOT marked as MMS in my twilio Account.**
And I can not understand what is wrong based on response (here are some of response parameters ):

[image]

Maybe someone has already done something similar or alredy worked with **Twilio ?**

*Any help will be appreciated.

thank you*

Comment: As per link you specified, media_url is an array (`media_url=['https://demo.twilio.com/owl.png'],`). That could be a potential issue.
It can also be a problem that url parameters are case sensitive -- MediaUrl instead of mediaURL

Comment: @kurunve thanks for response.
I tried a variant with the mediaURL as array.
Howevere response is the same.